# AngularJS Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:

Tags: angularjs

Estou com o seguinte erro para injeção de dependencias no meu controller:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProviderProvider <-
>   $routeProvider

Já importei o `angular-route` no meu HTML:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Já importei no módulo:

```
var module = angular.module('MainModule', ['ui.filters', 'ngRoute']);
```

Já importei no `controller`:

```
module.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeProvider',
function($scope, $routeProvider) {
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

Código:

```js
var module = angular.module('MainModule', ['ui.filters', 'ngRoute']);

module.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeProvider',
 function($scope, $routeProvider) {
 
 $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl : "consult.htm"
    })
    .when("/consult", {
        templateUrl : "consult.htm"
    })
    .when("/register", {
        templateUrl : "register.htm"
    });
 
}]);
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">   
<html>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui/0.4.0/angular-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
     <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  
  <script src="controller/controllerConsult.js"></script>
  <script src="controller/controllerMain.js"></script>
  <script src="provider/streaMusicProvider.js"></script>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

  <head>
   <title>StreaMusic</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     
   <div class="tabbable" ng-app="MainModule">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs padding-12 tab-color-blue background-blue" id="myTab">
     <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#consult">Consult</a></li>
  
     <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#register">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
  
    <div class="tab-content"  ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<!--      <div id="consult" class="tab-pane in active" ng-include="'consult.html'"  ng-controller="ConsultCtrl"> -->
<!--      </div> -->

     <div id="consult" class="tab-pane in active">
     
      <label class="textFilter">Filter by Category:
       <select ng-model="search.category">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option ng-repeat="x in musicList | unique:'category'">{{x.category}}</option>
       </select>
      </label>

      <label class="textFilter">Filter by Artist:
       <select ng-model="search.artist">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option ng-repeat="x in musicList | unique:'artist'">{{x.artist}}</option>
       </select>
      </label>
     
      <table id="music-table">
   
       <tr>
             <th>ARTIST</th>
             <th>MUSIC NAME</th>
             <th>ALBUM</th>
             <th>CATEGORY</th>
          </tr>
   
       <tr ng-repeat="x in musicList | filter:{'artist':  search.artist} | 
       filter:{'category':  search.category} | limitTo:10">
              <td>{{x.artist}}</td>
              <td>{{x.music}}</td>
              <td>{{x.album}}</td>
              <td>{{x.category}}</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
     </div>
  
     <div id="register" class="tab-pane">
      <p>TAB REGISTER</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Um `provider` só está disponível no ciclo de configuração:

```
var module = angular.module('MainModule', ['ui.filters', 'ngRoute']);

module.config(function($routeProvider) { // Ciclo de configuração
    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl : "consult.htm"
    });
});
```

Para utilizar durante o ciclo de execução, utilize o serviço diretamente:

```
//Utilize $route, não $routeProvider
module.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $route) { 
    $scope.route = $route;
});
```